# How to print the logs on the logcat (Android studio)

Tags: android-studio

Similar to the print function in java, that I need it to display some messages to help me debugging. But Logcat can't print the log messages. I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 (Mac).

Comment: Did you try using Log.d()? You can do something like Log.d("MyApp", "my message");

Comment: yes, I did Log.d(TAG, "message");

Comment: Make sure you enable `ADB integration`? `Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration`. Try to restart adb : `adb kill-server` -> `adb start-server`